# Texture Solid Option Is Not Showing Textured On 3D View port

Tags: texturing, uv

[image]

I unwrapped this cube and applied a grid texture into it. Then i Enabled [Textured Solid] Option from N panel. But It now showing textured on the display. I am not understanding , what is wrong with me and my blender [2.72]